# SQL join on multiple columns in same tables?

Tags: sql

I have a data table and a code table, And I want to join one column of the code table to two columns in the data table.

I didn't find a way to join so I tried:

```
SELECT
A.COLUMN1,
    (SELECT CODE_NAME FROM CODE_TABLE B WHERE B.CODE = A.COLUMN2) AS COLUMN2,
    (SELECT CODE_NAME FROM CODE_TABLE B WHERE B.CODE = A.COLUMN3) AS COLUMN3
FROM DATA_TABLE A ;

DATA_TABLE
COLUMN1 COLUMN2 COLUMN3
test     AA001    BB001
test1    AA002    BB002
test2    AA003    BB003

CODE_TABLE
CODE    CODE_NAME
AA001     APPLE
AA002     SAMSUNG
AA003     OPPO
BB001     LG
BB002     HWAWEI
BB003     GOOGLE
```

How to treat it as a join rather than a subquery?

Comment: Use two joins, one for each condition

Comment: And do `LEFT JOIN`, in case the CODE_TABLE row is missing for a DATA_TABLE row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can implement it as a `JOIN` with two independent `JOIN`s to `CODE_TABLE`, one for each value in `DATA_TABLE`:

```
SELECT A.COLUMN1,
       B1.CODE_NAME AS COLUMN2,
       B2.CODE_NAME AS COLUMN3
FROM DATA_TABLE A
JOIN CODE_TABLE B1 ON B1.CODE = A.COLUMN2
JOIN CODE_TABLE B2 ON B2.CODE = A.COLUMN3
```

If it's possible that a value from `COLUMN2` or `COLUMN3` in `DATA_TABLE` might not exist in `CODE_TABLE`, you should use `LEFT JOIN` instead, and `COALESCE` on the output so as not to return a `NULL` value:

```
SELECT A.COLUMN1,
       COALESCE(B1.CODE_NAME, '') AS COLUMN2,
       COALESCE(B2.CODE_NAME, '') AS COLUMN3
FROM DATA_TABLE A
LEFT JOIN CODE_TABLE B1 ON B1.CODE = A.COLUMN2
LEFT JOIN CODE_TABLE B2 ON B2.CODE = A.COLUMN3
```

Output (for your sample data)

```
COLUMN1 COLUMN2 COLUMN3
test    APPLE   LG
test1   SAMSUNG HWAWEI
test2   OPPO    GOOGLE
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/2DYyv5RuyTwP7X8sNDyL8a/1)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
    A.COLUMN1,
    B.CODE_NAME AS COLUMN2,
    C.CODE_NAME AS COLUMN3
FROM DATA_TABLE AS A
    INNER JOIN CODE_TABLE AS B ON B.CODE = A.COLUMN2
    INNER JOIN CODE_TABLE AS C ON C.CODE = A.COLUMN3
 ;
```

Note: Try and provide proper aliases, rather than A, B, c, in order to increase readability.